# Passing spaces conteined string to script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I use such small script to convert videos from my SAT receiver to h264/mp3 format.

```
[maciek@piotr Pobrane]$ cat ./conv_sat_to_clean_ts 
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i $1.ts -movflags +faststart -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 -f mpegts $1-new.ts
```

The problem is that when I call that script in such way:

```
./conv_sat_to_clean_ts ./Operacja\ Dunaj.ts
```

it shows me an error:

```
./Operacja: No such file or directory
```

So that means that spaces included in call parameters are ignored and filename is not interpreted correctly.
Is any way to resolve that problem?

Comment: You dont need .ts in your parameter as you take it like $1.ts. Shell is thinking that you are running a script with ./blah blah and hence error's out.

Comment: OK. So I change script to  -> ffmpeg -i $1 -movflags +faststart -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 -f mpegts NEW-$1 but the result is the same. That is -> ./Operacja: No such file or directory

Comment: remove ./ from ./Operacja while passing and see if that resolves although am not the expert in ffmpeg.

Comment: try giving file name in double quotes `"Operacja Dunaj"`

Comment: The same -> Operacja: No such file or directory

Comment: Does not matter is ./ present or double quotes. Still -> Operacja: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `$1` in double quotes since filename has space.

`ffmpeg -i "$1".ts -movflags +faststart -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 -f mpegts "$1"-new.ts`

and run the script without `.ts`

`./conv_sat_to_clean_ts ./Operacja\ Dunaj`

or

`./conv_sat_to_clean_ts "Operacja Dunaj"`

Comment: And it is possible to use .ts -> ffmpeg -i "$1" -movflags +faststart -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 -f mpegts NEW-"$1". And call script both -> ./conv_sat_to_clean_ts ./Operacja\ Dunaj.ts or -> ./conv_sat_to_clean_ts "Operacja Dunaj.ts". The key issue is to use double quotes in call parameter -> "$1"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. RBH was right. Now my script looks like this and work properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i "$1" -movflags +faststart -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 -f mpegts NEW-"$1"
```

And spaces in filenames (as script call parameter) are interpreted correctly